# How to get an object back from my executorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method, `spider`, that implements runnable that makes a http get to a webpage.

I have a private class in that same method that stores information about the webpage, elapsed time it took to download etc.

Now I have a list of urls which are consumed by my executorService that runs the `spider` method.

How can I get a list of urls that were processed, along with a stats for each url.

I need to get each thread to return that 'stat's object also along with the associated url.

Comment: callable, How are you doing the timeout? Are you using countdownlatch?

Answer (score 2):

When you send something to the `ExecutorService`, you should use the `submit` method, which returns a `Future` that can be used to access the result.  If you need to return a value, you should submit a `Callable<V>` object if you expect a `V` value to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [java.util.concurrent.Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).